# How do I make .load() wait till everything is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function loadContent(href){

    $('#loader').fadeIn(200, function () {

        $('#content').load(href + ' #content > *', function() {

            $('#loader').fadeOut(200);

        });
    });
}
```

Is it possible to only run `$('#loader').fadeOut(200);` after `$('#content').load(href + ' #content > *')` has finished loading its contents including images?

Comment: Maybe try this plugin ~ https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Comment: Why don't you just have a separate loading boxes on the images?

Comment: @Phil worked just fine, I guess this'll do.. Thanks!